# Modify Response Object in Slim 3 via external class

Tags: php, header, response, slim

I have a issue with my slim app, i want send json responses but with customed headers. My code is like follow:

index.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'app/config.php';
require 'app/libs/api.cs.php';

$app = new Slim\App(    
    [
        "settings" => $config,
        "apics" => function() { return new APIHelper(); } //This is a class that contain a "helper" for api responses
    ]
  );

require 'app/dependences.php';
require 'app/middleware.php';
require 'app/loader.php';
require 'app/routes.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

app/libs/api.cs.php (The "helper")

```
<?php
class APIHelper
{
    public function sendResponse($response, $status='success' ,$code = 200, $message = "", $data = null)
    {
      $arrResponse = array();  
      $arrResponse['status'] = $status;
      $arrResponse['code'] = $code;
      $arrResponse['message'] = $message;  
      $arrResponse['data'] = $data;
       return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, AeroTkn')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
        ->withHeader('X-Powered-By','My API Server')
        ->withJson($arrResponse,$code);
    }
}
```

my routes file (app/routes.php)

```
$app->group('/foo', function () {
  $this->get('', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    return $this->apics->sendResponse($res, 'success' ,200, "Foo API Index By Get", null);
});

  $this->post('', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    try{
        $oBody = $req->getParsedBody();
        return $this->apics->sendResponse($res, 'success' ,200, "Foo API POST Response", $oBody);        
      }
      catch(\Exception $ex){
        return $this->apics->sendResponse($res, 'error' ,500, "Process Error", array('error' => $ex->getMessage()));
    }   
  });
});
```

When i trying to run my app with request body, the result is the follow:
Headers:

```
connection →Keep-Alive
content-type →text/html
date →Wed, 30 Aug 2017 02:22:56 GMT
keep-alive →timeout=2, max=500
server →Apache
transfer-encoding →chunked
```

Body (returns as simple text and not json encoded)

```
{"status":"success","code":200,"message":"Foo API POST Response","data":{"one":"1", "two":"2"}}
```

I've trying put this class as a middleware, but i'm some confused in these subject.

Can you help me telling me if these method is good or where i'm bad.

Thanks to all and i hope for your answers! Nice day

Comment: What do you mean when you say `When i trying to run my app with request body`? Your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: Hi @Nima . 
Sorry, I did not write that part well, I would say that when I make a call for any method to my application, in the example I put above, I used the so-called post sending data in the body of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Middleware is the ideal answer for your problem

Just add this function in your middeleware file

```
 $app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
        $response = $next($req, $res);
        return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mysite')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
         ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
         ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        ->withHeader('X-Powered-By','My API Server');
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Ramy hakam . Thanks for the comment!, Yo know? it's very strange, because these sounds the ideal solution as you said, i've tried the same solution but with the difference that you exclude the json scheme preparation, i've separate my code, putting the headers customization in the middleware and the json scheme i've leave it in the service. But the custom response headers still without appears, also the "transfer-encoding" has the value "chunked".

Answer (score 0):

I found the "error" was a kindergarden issue hahaha, I've download all my code from the web server for test in my machine, I have the same result, but i found that all my files had strange characters at start, so i re-save the files as utf-8 and the problem is solved. Little details that can create headaches!. Thanks to Nica and Ramy. Ramy: the solution was excellent, now the code are more organizated, i take this practice. Good day to all.